# High Thread Counts - JVM becoming unresponsive - Tomcat 8.5.13

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, tomcat8

We face intermittent High Thread Counts followed by JVM's slowdown and during the same timeframe, we could find the below mentioned exceptions. Please suggest if these are SYMPTOMS or CAUSES and help understand the remediation steps.

> Mar 23, 2022 2:44:13 PM org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter checkRecycled
> INFO: Encountered a non-recycled response and recycled it forcedly.
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter$RecycleRequiredException
>
> Mar 23, 2022 2:57:56 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler process
> SEVERE: Error reading request, ignored
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Inflater has been closed

Comment: An excessive thread count can lead to slow down, especially if you have overcommitted memory.  Generally speaking, having lots of threads is not a good thing.  However, Tomcat does not create an excessive number of worker threads unless you configure it to.  Those exceptions look consequential rather than causal.  But there is not enough information to draw any real conclusions.

Comment: Upgrade to lastest Java and Tomcat 8.5.x first.

Comment: @michael-o These are our current versions : Java.version : 1.8.0_302 and Tomcat : 8.5.13 | Are you aware of any issues that I have mentioned in my original post related to these versions ? Also, any recommendations regarding TO-BE upgraded versions of Java and Tomcat 8.5.x ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @StephenC 
 We see a sudden spike in JVM active sessions followed by increase in JVM thread counts, no clues about these sessions from any other monitoring tools or logs. Please let me know the artifacts to be supplied here to help look into the real cause.

Comment: It could be that your server is just getting overloaded by a bunch of requests happening at the same time.  Get hold of the request logs and see if you can spot any correlations.  Turn on GC logging and see if you can spot any correlations. Have you spoken to the developers who designed and implemented your web applications?

Comment: .13 is ages old.

Comment: @Michael-O  What is your recommended STABLE Tomcat 8.5.x or Tomcat 9.x versions ?

Comment: The lastest available. Upgrade every two to three months otherwise they list of changes might be too large to test reasonably.

Comment: @Michael-O Unfortunately, we cannot keep upgrading frequently. In addition, any idea where can we find the exact differences between two different versions of a Tomcat to test the new changes ?